# Duplicate question with downvotes

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, downvotes, deleted-questions, quality-improvement

I have recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77666286/replace-newline-followed-by-foo-with-bar) that was marked duplicate and received two downvotes. There aren't any answers to my question, only a comment with a
link to another post that answered my question.

I would like to improve my question, but I do not see a way to do that, because it is just a duplicate. So I thought it should be just deleted, but I have read that it is almost always a bad thing to delete a question. Is there anything I can do to avoid leaving a question with two downvotes on the site?

Comment: I am not an expert in Perl, not even a beginner, and so I cannot address any of the specifics of your main-site issue, but if you are on the cusp of a question ban, then consider to work on improve the question, if possible, and to avoid deletion. If not, then the deletion of one closed question won't matter too much (as I understand things). I have notified one of the gold-badge dupe closers of this discussion as well to see if there is anything to add.

Comment: Not really. It's now functioning as a signpost to the duplicate. I wouldn't worry about a couple of downvotes... treat it as a learning experience to creating better, more researched, questions in the future.

Comment: The downvotes *could* be because of an apparent lack of research, that *is* a reason to downvote a question (it's in the tool tip) and if it's a duplicate (especially an easily found duplicate ) then users can (and will) downvote the question. In such cases there may well not be a way to improve th question.

Comment: If the answer to the existing question answered your question then your question absolutely is a duplicate of that question. You were provided feedback on the limits of what you attempted, and a suggested workaround, but you have made no improvements to your question to indicate any problems with that workaround. How you avoid downvotes is by asking high quality questions, and yes that guidance is broad, for a reason because it’s multilayered

Comment: The existing duplicate is too unspecific. There is likely a more specific duplicate somewhere.

Comment: It *might* be one of the few cases where ChatGPT could produce a correct solution (thus no need to post a question on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes I am on the cusp of a question ban. 
I wanted to post a question this morning but I saw a warning notice to that effect. I have in fact always done a lot of research before posting a question, and I usually post only after a few days of attempts on my own, but  a search is often only as effective as the keywords one uses. Not knowing enough about the right words to use is part of the problem, but as for doing my homework, I do try my best. I have now edited the original question to add details and examples, as pointed out in the answer to this post.

Comment: @ Paulie_D Yes it is definitely a learning experience and I am doing my best to ask better questions. But I have always done a lot of search before posting. Unfortunately I do need to worry about the downvotes because I received a warning that I could be banned from posting questions, and so I did not post this morning as I had planned to. I have received VERY helpful answers from the site in the past. In an attempt to compensate for the fact that I only get help from here and do not (know how to) contribute much, I contribute to other stackexchange forums where I am able to do so.

Comment: @ThomA I have now added some details to my question that was downvoted. I had in fact done a lot of search but I think that without using the right keywords even an easily found duplicate may become difficult to find.

Comment: @SecurityHound It seems that some comments were deleted when the question was closed (and surely my comment that the duplicate's answer solved my problem was deleted), and I do not remember what was suggested, but I do remember that I tried to do whatever I was able to do. If I did not follow some of the suggestions it was probably because the problem had been solved and I thought it may be more useful to a reader to see the answer that fully solved it, rather than detailing my failed attempts. But now that my comment has been deleted it may appear as if I just ignored the suggestions.

Comment: @Valerio - I looked at the question, when a question is closed any automatically generated comments, asking if a question answers your question are deleted because the comment is automatically generated when a user without a gold tag votes to close a question as a duplicate. In other words, a comment asking a question which wasn’t actually a question, was automatically deleted when the question was properly closed as a duplicate which you admit answered your question

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that you being close to a question ban isn’t due to a singular question that turned out to be a duplicate but more of a pattern of questions that were not well received. Yes, indeed that is a broad description, because it’s the best way to explain your current situation.  However, deleting the duplicate question isn’t an option, that will just make matters work. Asking a question and then deleting it should absolutely be avoided unless the question cannot be improved (for instance the problem was caused by a typo)

Comment: @SecurityHound I have posted a total of 15 questions. Besides the question discussed here (with 2 downvotes), I only had 1 downvote on a question, and then I have 9 questions with 0, 3 with 1 upvote and 1 with 6 upvotes. So the algebraic sum is that I have a total of 6 upvotes. I imagine that in order to be close to a ban, maybe the questions with 0 should also be considered bad? If that is the case, I will try to improve them. I do try my best when I post. I am aware that I only receive (VERY valuable) help without giving it, but I do not know how to help here. I do help on the math forum.

Comment: How many deleted questions do you have? If you really have 9 questions with at least 1 upvote you shouldn’t be question banned. So the only explanation is you have deleted questions that you had asked the past

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't have any deleted questions. But I have 9 questions with 0 (not 1) upvotes. Then 3 with 1 upvote and 1 with 6 upvotes. I noticed now that if I begin posting a question, I no longer receive the warning. Maybe because the downvotes in my last question went from 2 to 1.

Comment: @Valerio - You don’t have enough downvoted questions that haven’t been deleted to be question banned.

Comment: Do you actually need to find a *newline before* the text? or do you really want to find the text *at the beginning of a line* (including the first line of the file)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes I really needed to newline before the text. Because that was the only way I could distinguish that spot from many others in the document with the same text, but not preceded by a newline. In nay case, my problem was completely solved by the answer to the duplicate question pointed out when this question was closed. I had posted a comment to indicate this but it was deleted when the question was closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another user cast the first close vote with the duplicate target.  After I looked at the duplicate, I concurred with the other user, and I cast the second close vote, which closed the question (because I have dupehammer powers).

I applied the solution in the duplicate's accepted answer, and it worked for me.  I created a short input file for myself, ran the `perl` command with the `-0777` option, and it properly replaced `\nfoo` with `bar` in the file.  I ran this on Linux because I do not have access to macOS.  Here is the exact command I used:

```
perl -0777 -pi -w -e 's/\nfoo/bar/g;' file
```

> I would like to improve my question, but I do not see a way to do that

I recommend that you edit your question to add more details.  For example:

1. Add the contents of your input file *before* you run the `perl` command.  It would be best to use 5 lines or less.
2. Add the contents of the in-place edited file that you would like to see *after* you run the `perl` command.

I know nothing about macOS and what newline characters are used.  If it uses something different from Linux, then perhaps the newlines get translated into something else when you post your file contents into the question.  It may be difficult for people to reproduce.  Also, take a look at [perldoc perlport](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport#Newlines).

Your question mentions that the `\n` replacement by itself does work, so I don't expect newlines to be a problem.

Comment: I have edited the question. I added details and the content of the input file as you suggested. The duplicate's accepted answer also worked for me and it completely solved my problem. I wrote that as a comment in my original question but apparently the comment was deleted when the question was closed.

Comment: @Valerio - Your comment saying the duplicate answered your question was unnecessary, upvote the answer, but if the duplicate answered your question then your question being closed as a duplicate is a positive thing.

Comment: @SecurityHound Yes I have now upvoted that answer after your comment (I thought I had done it at the time but apparently I had not). I have tried to improve my duplicate question, and it's good to hear its being closed is a positive thing, but unfortunately after I posted this question on meta the downvotes went from 2 to 3. I had originally hoped to improve my situation because I would like to post a question but I received a warning that I may receive a ban if I do so. Any suggestions of what else I may try would be greatly appreciated.